# Which registry to use to detect .NET versions

Tags: .net, registry, .net-framework-version

What is the best registry path to detect .NET versions? I want to detect version 2.0 and 4.0.

Many people suggest many path like:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy\v4.0
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4.0
```

Which one is the best?

I have the following frameworks installed:

```
.NET 2.0 SP 2
.NET 3.0 SP 2
.NET 3.5 SP 1
.NET 4.5
.NET 4.5.1
```

but `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP` does not have `v4.5` or `v4.5.1` key in it. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework\policy` does not have `3.5`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework` has two keys for v4.5: `v4.5` and `v4.5.50709` keys. So, which one to use to detect 4.5?

I am very confused.

Comment: You don't have those versions installed.  .NET Framework updates *replace* their older version.  You only have 3.5SP1 and 4.5.1.  Whatever the X might be in this XY problem is surely something you should not be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MSDN [How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx):

- Versions 1 - 4: use `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP`
- Versions 4.5+: use `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`, and check the `Release` DWORD for specific versions

Comment: I only have a `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client` entry, but no `Full`, and a program I'm trying to install complains about an unsupported NET framework version even though I just installed 4.6.2 and that's what the program asks for...

Answer (score 0):

An important addition to the answer of admdrew
[MSDN How to: Determine Which .NET Framework Versions Are Installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx)

Be aware that the MSDN link above mixes up two paths in the description and code example!

While the section *"To find .NET Framework versions by querying the registry in code (.NET Framework 4.5 and later)"* states you should use

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4.0\Full
```

the code sample in the same link uses the following path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
```

(Please note the difference: "v4.0" vs. "v4")

I noticed .NET 4 installations may use either folder, so it does make sense to check both! It seems like different installers and/or versions use different paths (online installer, offline installer, pre-installed with Windows, .NET 4.0 Client, .NET 4.0 Full, ...)

If you want to reliably detect .NET 4, you have to check the `Install` entry on both paths.